# How to remove specific number of line from existing file and create new text file

Tags: c#, text-files, read-write

I have a text file which is have n number of line, I have extracted few line (suppose 10 lines) from the existing file. Now I want to delete those 10 line from the from the existing file and create the new file with all existing data after removing those 10 lines.

```
 private void ReWriteFile(string NewFileName)
 {            
    List<string> linetoDelete = _errorLine;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
    {
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(NewFileName))
       {
               // reading the old file remove the error line and create new file                   

        }
     }
 }
```

Please help me with example.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the exact issue you had with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void ReWriteFile(string NewFileName) {

        List<String> _errorLine = new List<string>() {
            "Error Line 1", "Error Line 2"
        };

        String _fileName = "InputFile.txt";
        String _outputFile = NewFileName;

        List<string> linetoDelete = _errorLine;


        String[] sourceLines = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);

        if (sourceLines.Length > 0) {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_outputFile)) {
                foreach(String line in sourceLines) {
                    if (!_errorLine.Contains(line)) {
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Reading and writing to text files is a rudimentary part of programming, and your question lacks any evidence of attempting to solve the issue yourself.

A few points to consider.

1) When you are reading a text file for processing, load the lot into an array of `String` objects. The source will not change while you're processing it, so there's no need to keep a reader open holding a handle on the file.

2) Deleting content from a file is a bad approach, as you are potentially changing the file while processing it. This will cause issues as you're enumerating the file at the time (assuming you are using a reader in a loop).

3) My approach is not perfect - if the `_errorLine` list is long, and the source file is also long, there will be a lot of calls to check whether the `_errorLines` list contains a particular `String`. There will be a faster way to do this, but I haven't the time to do any extensive testing.

4) As a follow on to point 3, this code is not tested and may need small adjustment to get it working correctly.

Finally, when posting a question on SO, showing that you have at least tried to resolve the issue is a better option than just giving us a skeleton example and asking us to do your work for you.

Please refer to the following pages for information on reading/writing from files.

The number of fresh graduate programmers I've seen who can't code up basic IO functions like this is somewhat disconcerting!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I never got interest in reading/writing file, which make my life difficult some time.

Comment: This is the issue. When I started programming, it was on the Atari ST, then Basic for DOS. File reading and writing in low level languages is a fundamental, and every programmer should understanding with no exceptions. In modern environments, file access is essential for analyzing log files and processing config files, and IMO, not knowing how to do it properly shows a gap in knowledge that has to be plugged.

Comment: It seams as if university only teaches high level theoretic crap but fails to teach basics like `HelloWorld`.

Comment: We went from HelloWorld to simulating lottery results. Had I not had 12 years background in programming at amateur level (and 2 years professionally) by that point, I would have had real problems.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    private void ReWriteFile(string _newFileName)
    {
        List<string> linetoDelete = _errorLine;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_newFileName))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(!linetoDelete.Contains(line))
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want remove specific number of line

```
string line;
int index = 0; // index line from file
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!index++ != number) // number - it is your specific number of line from '0' to 'N' (for example 'number = 1' - write all lines except for line number one)
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

if you want remove many lines:

```
List<int> numberOfDeleteLines =  new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
...
string line;
int index = 0;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!numberOfDeleteLines.Contains(index++))
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```